# Consistency in uniform distribution

Tags: self-study, estimation, inference, consistency

[image]

I know what consistency is but in options C and D both U and V are given whose covariance is quite difficult to find.

Comment: Perhaps you could demonstrate consistency without actually computing the covariance.  For instance, could you find upper bounds for the variances of these estimators?  Another approach is to analyze the joint distribution of $(U,V)$ directly: as $n$ grows large, it is intuitively obvious that it becomes focused near the point $(\theta+1,\theta),$ so the question comes down to demonstrating that somehow.

Comment: Well I couldn't find the bounds but do you have a shorter method to determine since this came on an exam and i dont think i would have so much time to delve into those.

Comment: Do you need to justify your answers on the exam or not?  If not, then (in light of the intuition I described) you're practically done, because all you have to do is compute the expectations of the four estimators.  If you do need a rigorous justification, do you know any theorems about functions of consistent estimators (such as linear combinations of them)?  If so, they should settle the matter easily and quickly.

Comment: No I'm not familiar with any such thorem but is it helpful in solving  problems like above?

Comment: Clearly such a theorem would be helpful when looking at C and D

Comment: @glen_n do you know ? Could you please share?

Comment: Same question on math.se: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2658616/obtaining-consistent-estimators-based-on-uniform-distribution.

Answer (score 2):

Start with some intuition.  As $n \rightarrow \infty$ we should expect that the sample minimum and maximum converge to the lower and upper bounds of the support respectively.  That is, we expect that $U \rightarrow \theta+1$ and $V \rightarrow \theta$.  That should give you an intuitive method to determine which of the claims is true.  To prove that formally, you could make use of the joint distribution of the two [order statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic).

Comment: +1.  However, I think you don't need to use the joint distribution, because an analysis of the marginal distributions ought to suffice.

Comment: Yeah, maybe, but only if you establish asymptotic independence first.  I'd think that for (C) and (D) you'd need to consider the interaction, since both order statistics appear in the function.

Comment: I don't think that's necessary.  If you can show that $U$ converges in probability to $\theta+1$ and $V$ to $\theta,$ why would their joint distribution matter at all?

Comment: Well, you'd need *something* to go from those two marginal conditions, to the condition $f(U,V) \rightarrow f(\theta+1, \theta)$ in a function of both variables.  Maybe that's guaranteed by the marginal convergence of each random variable, but if so, I'd at least want to see the theorem that ensures it.

Comment: Don't get me wrong.  I'm sure it holds in this case, but if I were deriving the result, I'd  want to have some justification for going from the marginal convergence steps to asserting convergence of the bivariate function.  I'm a bit rusty on convergence theorems, so maybe you're aware of the relevant result and I'm not, but there would have to *be* a result that justifies this step.  (I'm assuming it would probably require $f$ to be continuous, which holds in this case.)

Comment: I believe the "result" you might be referring to follows easily from the definition of convergence in probability.